# Mi class no encuentra mis layouts ni activities android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, activity, class

Mi aplicación esta conectada a un servidor de firebase, y he creado una clase para que compruebe si se han cambiado los datos y, si es así vaya a un layout o una activity en concreto:

```
package com.example.gerard.presentacio;
import com.example.gerard.presentacio.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

/**
 * Created by Gerard on 2/12/2017.
 */

public class check extends Activity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("num");
    public String id;
    private int diapo;
    private static Context context;
    public void checkeja(){
        if(diapo==1){
            setContentView(R.layout.diapo1);
        }
        if(diapo==2){
            setContentView(R.layout.diapo2);
        }
        if(diapo==3){
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Nom.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if(diapo==4){
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), edat.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
    public void update() {
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                //TextView mostra = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.actual);
                int value = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
                diapo=value;
                checkeja();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
              //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.class, "Error de connecció", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicación se detiene y me saltan los siguientes errores diciendo que no se encuentran los layouts ni las activities:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.gerard.presentacio, PID: 25522
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.Window.setContentView(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2548)
>                         at com.example.gerard.presentacio.check.checkeja(check.java:27)
>                         at com.example.gerard.presentacio.check$1.onDataChange(check.java:51)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
>   Application terminated.

He intentado usar el mismo código en el MainActivity y funciona bien, he estado buscando por aquí a ver si a alguien más le había pasado pero he visto que soy el único, así que supongo que será que no he extendido bien la clase o algun que otro error básico.

Muchas grácias de antemano

Comment: Recomendación en una actividad no puedes cambiar el Layout de manera dinámica, si requieres hacerlo dinámico tienes que usar Fragments.
El problema básicamente es que no puedes hacer un setContentView() de manera dinámica en una actividad. Este método se admite únicamente en el onCreate a la hora de inflar el Layout.

La solución si es posible, es usar fragments o levantar otras actividades como en el caso del condicional 3 y 4

Comment: "He intentado usar el mismo código en el MainActivity y funciona bien", cual es el código que funciona incorrectamente?

Comment: @GustavoMora también puede usarse fuera de onCreate() (estando dentro de la misma Activity) y puede cambiarse dinamicamente el layout.

Comment: @Jorgesys Me refiero a que la culpa supongo que es de la clase ya que cuando lo he movido al MainActivity ha hecho lo que se suponía que tenía que hacer

Comment: @gery_08 como llamas el m´todo update() ???  En realidad debes agregar un onCreate() para tu Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una Activity pero no tienes especificado el método `onCreate()`, 
 debes agregarlo y posteriormente puedes cambiar el layout mediante

```
 setContentView(R.layout.<layout>)
```

**El problema, estas llamando el método `setContentView()` de una Activity que no esta creada**, en este caso llamas desde la Activity: `MainActivity` llamas el método `update()` de la Activity: `check` pero esta no ha pasado por `onCreate()`!

Comment: Ya lo he añadido pero sigue dandome el mismo error, el método update lo he llamado desde mi MainActivity con el código: `check dc = new check();
        dc.update();` donde check es la clase que he enseñado

Comment: Es que precisamente ese es el problema, estas llamando el método setContentView() de una Activity que no esta creada, en este caso check

Comment: Y una vez añadido el onCreate como tengo que llamar al método?

Comment: Es importante que si llamas setContentView() es porque la Activity esta visible, no funciona si llamas el método desde otra Activity o clase.

Comment: Entonces no merece la pena poner ese código en un archivo a parte y hacer referencia a él desde todas las activities, sinó que lo tengo que poner en cada Activity no?

Comment: exacto, si deseas usar setContentView() debe ser desde la misma Actitiy para cambiar el layout de la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han mencionado no respetas el ciclo de vida de una actividad. Al parecer creas primero la clase y luego el `layout` y no has creado el enlace entre estos dos componentes.

Existe una forma de generar el enlace entre la clase y el `layout` automáticamente, es decir te genere el `onCreate` ... Ejemplo :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemplo);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Simplemente sigue estos pasos :

```
Paquete Java > Paquete de clases > New > Activity
```

Con otro crearas una `clase` y un `XML` con el mismo nombre y podrás usarla sin problemas, hay podrías hacer tu validación para `firebase`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que no estas respetando los ciclos de vida de un actividad. El metodo `setContentView` solo se debe utilizar cuando se ejecute el método [`onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=es-419#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) y es muy probable que tu no lo estés haciendo.

Tambien ten en cuenta que no deberías de actualizar el layout de una actividad dinamicamente, ya que tendirias que agregar todos los eventos correspondientes a esa vista al momento de cambiar por lo que para eso se crearon los [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=es-419)s.

Comment: Una cerveza para este amigo por favor!!!